# Need to get file name from user while accessing form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to get input for file name from form. While running Appscript I am able to get prompt to get input from user, whereas, while trying via form, prompt is not showing . I have tried with below Appscript.

```
 var ui = FormApp.getUi();
 var response = ui.prompt('Getting to know you', 'May I know your file name?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
 var userResponse = response.getResponseText();
 var app=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DpeeCNeqCN2Bm2pWxf4TiMEaM6MEhSx8GfP6CuyI/edit#gid=0");
 app.copy(userResponse);
```

Additional information (from a comment by the questioner):
Actually i am trying to copy one spreadsheet from one account and trying to open in another account. At run time i am trying to get file name to be saved and open. So that i have used copy(). Ask is i have copied the sheet from another account and able to get prompt while running via script were as i am trying with same script via for am not getting prompt to get user input filename.

Comment: Welcome. Would you please explain why you are using an `ui` prompt in a FORM, rather than just include a question in the Form to enter a file name?

Comment: You said _Now i am able to open while running the script. were as while trying from not able to open._ does this mean that you have solved your problem?